# How do we synthetis a peptoid from beta-Alanine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I did a reaction that contains 4 steps described in this picture :
[image]

I understood that this 3 steps helped me to synthetis the NGlu part but I don't know why did we do alkylation ? It can't be a protection because otherwise why did we deprotected it before ? Can someone help me please to understand. I read somewhere that it is used as a linker but I don't understand how it can help to polymerize and have a longer chain

Comment: You have effectively added a glycine unit

Comment: @Waylander how is that a glycine ?

Comment: look at the unit at the right hand end - it is NH2-CH2-CO2Et - which is Gly-OEt

Comment: @Waylander Oh I understand so it's a way to make the peptoids longer ? what if I want to add another peptoid how should I do ? What is the role of OEt ?

Comment: I have olso a question about the protection of the carboxilic acid, does its protection makes it very stable ?

Comment: Which carboxylic acid? It is entirely possible to selectively hydrolyse either ester. The tBu ester can be hydrolysed by anhydrous acid (TFA/DCM does this well). Mild base hydroysis (LiOH/THF/water) will hydrolyse the Et ester selectively. Either one can be selectively cleaved and then extended by use of an amine + coupling agent. Many coupling agents based on carbodiimides are used for this.

Comment: @Waylander I talk about the reaction from Cbz-beta-Ala-OH to the Cbz-beta-Ala-OtBu

Comment: when you say "look at the unit at the right hand end - it is NH2-CH2-CO2Et - which is Gly-OEt ": Does it mean I have a pseudo peptide composed of 2 amino acid : Glu and Gly ?

Comment: Yes, you have a pseudopeptide of beta-Ala-Glu. The tBu ester of Cbz-beta-Ala is generally quite stable with well-defined conditions for removing the tBu group.